elasticsearch create remote snapshot repository
I want to create a snapshot repository on centos es. This repository is a folder in local macos.
but, error
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "repository_exception",
                "reason": "[my_backup] missing url"
            }
        ],
        "type": "repository_exception",
        "reason": "[my_backup] failed to create repository",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "repository_exception",
            "reason": "[my_backup] missing url"
        }
    },
    "status": 500
}

Run python3 -m http.server 8000 in the macos folder to start the service

Can be accessed on centos

elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: test-elasticsearch
node.name: es-node0
path.data: /opt/elasticsearch/data
path.logs: /opt/elasticsearch/logs
network.host: 0.0.0.0
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["es-node0"]
http.port: 9401
repositories.url.allowed_urls: "http://192.168.100.226:8000"

reload es ,send request has error

